# Appending a string to a TypeScript object type, where property names are derived from a string literal type

Tags: typescript

I would like to dynamically define a type like this from a list of currency ids:

```
{
  usd: number;
  usd_mcap: number;
  eur: number;
  eur_mcap: number;
  gbp: number;
  gbp_mcap: number;
}
```

I have the following, but I cannot figure out how to add the `{currency}_mcap` property to the object:

```
type CurrencyId = 'usd' | 'eur' | 'gbp';
type AssetInfo = {
  [key in CurrencyId]: number;
} & {
  [(key + '_mcap') in CurrencyId]: number; // This does not work
}
```

Any ideas what I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) for this:

```js
type CurrencyId = 'usd' | 'eur' | 'gbp';

// as a Record
type AssetInfoRecord = Record<CurrencyId | `${CurrencyId}_mcap`, number>;

// as an Object
type AssetInfoObject = {
  [key in CurrencyId | `${CurrencyId}_mcap`]: number;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that has worked perfectly. I had no idea that Template Literal Types even existed!